Should I say "I only need to develop iOS games, rather than other non-game apps", "I need to develop only iOS games …", or some other wording?
Swift is a programming language for developing iOS apps. However, some game engines such as Unity, uses other languages, such as C#.
to inquire whether I need writing Swift, should I ask

If I only need to develop iOS games, rather than other non-game apps, should I learn Swift?

,

If I need to develop only iOS games, rather than other non-game apps, should I learn Swift?

, or some other wording?

We should place modifiers close to their modificands.  In the OP's example, the intended modificand is clearly iOS games.  We should hence use the second version although I believe the first should also be understood.
